# How to call a R program from another R program?

Tags: r

Is it possible to call a R program with in a R program?

Say for example, I am looking for something like this:

```
If condition == X{
   CALL "Pgm A"
  } else {
     CALL "Pgm B"
 }
```

This kind of syntax I have used in C. Is there a way similar in R?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by R "program?"  A script running in R is merely just that: an interpreted script running inside the R console.  Do you want to launch another R console, or something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Thanks for replying. What i meant is I am writing the R scripts in the form of a program to suit my requirement. What i meant in the above code is that I will be write two/three different R scripts, and i want to call one script from the other.

Comment: Are you looking for `source`?

Comment: @alistaire - Thanks for the input

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should do

```
if(condition==X){
    source("program_A.R")
}else{
    source("program_B.R")
}
```

Comment: Important: the script you call with `source()` will by default see any objects and variables that you are currently using in your R session. This may cause problems, especially when debugging. For example, your script may call some variable `x` that is not defined in the script. However, if you defined eg `x <- 3` in your R session, the script will use that value for `x`. To avoid this if unintended, call source with the local argument: `source( ... , local=TRUE)` instead.